# Testing Ray and Triangle Intersections Efficiently -- Memory Data Structures

Tags: performance, math, data-structures, 2d, processing-efficiency

I have a large collection of "Line Segments" and "Lines" in 2D, integer space. Given this set, I want to store it in memory in such a way that the latency of the following methods/queries is minimal. I'm looking for a language independent data structure which most efficiently satisfies the following conditions, and why it's a good choice.

Definitions:

- Point -- A point is represented by a (X,Y) pair. These are Int64s
- Line Segment -- A pair of Points. Of these Points, one is "Start" and the other is "End"
- Triangle -- A set of Three Points, or could also be defined by three Line Segments, which form the simplest geometric shape

Operations

- IsPointInTriangle(Point) -- Return True/False if a given point is inside of ANY stored triangle
- IsPointOnLine Segment(Point) -- Return True/False is a given point lies on a Line Segment
- DoesLine SegmentCrossOtherLine Segments(Line Segment) -- Return True/False if a given line segment would cross ANY other Line Segments
- GetPotentialTriangles(Line Segment) -- Returns a set of potential Triangles if this Line Segment was added to the set that would be created. That is return an arline segment of 3 Points/Line Segments making up zero+ triangles.

Goals and Assumptions:

- Operations and data reside in memory. Storage cost is a non-issue
- Operations need not be thread safe. Each operation will take place sequentially
- No point will be stored which lies in an existing Triangle
- No point will be stored which lies on an existing Line Segment
- No Line Segment will be stored which crosses an existing Line Segment
- Reduction in latency for each calculation is the ultimate goal. All other concerns are secondary.

Comment: @Teepeemm, true. I'll edit.